# Form onsubmit not working when loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

When the below content is loaded via Ajax its not working:

```
<form action="...." onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to cancel this plan?');">
```

The confirm dialog box does not appear. There are multiple form with same action. The binding using Jquery wouldn't work as there isn't a single id. Shall I bind using jquery on event using a class name?

Comment: write in onclick button event , onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to cancel this plan?');"

Answer (score -1):

You better use the `onclick` event of your submit button(s).

For example:

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='undo' value='Undo' onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to cancel this plan?');"/>
</form>
```